# Driving one activity LED with two inputs (TX/RX)

Tags: arduino, operational-amplifier, serial

I want one LED to indicate both TX and RX activity. The TXD/RXD inputs come from an Atmega328 connected to a MAX485 (RS485 IC). The output of the op-amp would go via a cable to a remote LED with a resistor (ACT). Is this the correct way to connect this?

I know the TX/RX lines probably are enough to drive a LED, but it may be a long cable and I don't want to introduce any issues, hence the op-amp.

I know the TX/RX lines are idle high and I don't mind if the ACT light stays on when idle and blinks when there is data.

[image: Schematic]

Comment: If TXD or RXD do not go negative below GND then both op-amps will output a high continuously. If they do go significantly below GND then you stand a chance of burning the op-amps.

Comment: I’d be looking at logic gates rather than op-amps. 74hct00 maybe.

Comment: Keep in mind that TTL signals (RXD from Atmega) are normally negated. Activity starts when they go low.

Comment: How do you control the MAX485 RE and DE lines?

Comment: @Justme PD2 pin on Atmega328, on the software side its handled by DCS-BIOS.

Comment: Have you considered triggering the activity LED from the Atmega directly, using software? That would reduce part count considerably. Or do you need to see activity even if the Atmega is non-responsive for some reason?

Comment: @Hans-MartinMosner, that wouldn't show actual activity on the lines, the other side of the transceivers, though.

Answer (score 14):

The circuit you'd want should have three primary functions:

1. Logically OR-ing the transmit and receive signals (OR in negative logic, since they are active low - so that's an AND).
2. Extending the pulse duration - to capture even single start bits (when the byte is 0xFF).
3. Driving the LED.

The circuit below does it. R1-R2 are the AND gate, Q1 is the R3-C1 charger, Q2 senses the RC voltage and drives the LED. The R3||R4 * C1 time constant determines how long are the stretched output pulses.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fWnRib.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Given a 115,200 baud rate, a byte transmitted at 0ms, and a byte received at 1ms, the input voltages', capacitor voltage, and R5 voltage drop (current) are as shown below:

[image: The waveforms of RXD and TXD signals, capacitor voltage, and LED current sense voltage in the 2-transistor circuit]

The op-amps are not necessary for this. If you really wanted to have a sharp LED turn-off, a couple more transistors would do the job:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2foPYpd.png)</sup>

Q2-Q3 is a differential pair configured as a comparator of R3-C1 voltage to mid-supply reference formed by R7-R8. Q5 is the output driver. C2 helps prevent oscillation.

[image: The waveforms of RXD and TXD signals, capacitor voltage, and LED current sense voltage in the 4-transistor circuit]

**Note**: The previous versions of the circuits have used diodes for the AND function. The current version has simplified things a bit :)

Comment: I’ve got a 5V circuit, do i need to change the resistor values?

Comment: Try it. But I doubt there’s much to adjust. Maybe R6 in the 2nd circuit. And of course the LED series resistor.

Answer (score 11):

Probably the simplest solution would be to use a 555 timer as a monostable with 5 passives, plus the LED with resistor and supply decoupling needed by any circuit.

The shortest LOW pulse on TXD or RXD is the single START bit that begins the sending of 0xFF followed by the HIGH of STOP bit(s).

A falling edge from TXD or RXD will pull the 555's TRIG input pin LOW through the diodes, triggering the monostable. Pulses <1 us will trigger it so up to 1 Mbaud or so could be used.

The 20 ms monostable will light the LED for at least 20 ms, with further TXD/RXD activity extending that pulse out.

From experience and experimentation, I've found that time a good compromise for serial activity: long enough to be easily seen, short enough to flicker over longer comms and show a sign of life.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fZWucf.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 4):

The default state for RO is going to be high with no activity, so you would want a low signal to turn on the LED.  In that case an AND gate (or NAND gate) makes the most sense because it handles the logic of driving the LED when either signal is low, and it also provides drive current for the LED.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f4VS0D.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: RO will be high-z mode when RE is high. May or may not affect your solution.

Comment: @Justme Well if RO is driving an MCU then it can't float under any circumstances.  I would assume that the internal IO pin pullup on the MCU would have to be enabled, or else an external one would be added.

Answer (score 3):

A slightly more complex solution would be to use both halves of a [74HC123](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn74ahc123a.pdf) with two RC networks to stretch pulses from both TXD and RXD and then combine the two pulse outputs as so:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f6udT1.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Pick some time such as 100ms that is easily visible. That way a single character sent at, say, 115,200 baud (less than 0.1ms) will be easily seen.

---

Your LM358 circuit is level sensitive so it will work for slower transmitted data, but you you have to bias the op-amp inputs above ground (half of power supply voltage, for example, with a couple resistors) and you would want to detect the voltage falling below the supply voltage since RXD/TXD lines at the MCU both idle high). It has the advantage that the op-amp output can withstand a short circuit.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fB5E80.png)</sup>

You could also combine the two op-amp outputs with a BJT as in my circuit.

Note that you're exceeding the valid op-amp input range with the inputs when they are at +5V however that yields the correct output **in this particular case** (LM358) since the non-inverting input is within the valid range (2.5V).

Comment: In the first circiut the LED would only be off if RX and TX are both active at the same time.

Comment: @Jens the inputs are the active-high Q pulse outputs of the 74HC123, not the TXD and RXD signals.

Comment: Ah, yes, that is the trick, my brain insufficiency.

Answer (score 2):

I would try something like this. Values likely to be adjusted at your taste.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2foRvZZ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: If you used a base series resistor (say, 47K) in a rearranged circuit, the LED would stay on for much longer.

Answer (score 1):

There are Open Collector / Open Drain [comparators](https://eu.mouser.com/c/semiconductors/amplifier-ics/analog-comparators/?output%20type=Open%20Collector%2C%20Open%20Drain) which could replace you op-amps and whose outputs can be joined together without any diodes to create a logical OR signal that you could then use to drive your LED.